# He arrived “breathless” at the top of the stairs

Tags: adjectives, adverbs, adverb-placement

I came across this sentence when I looked up the word **breathless** in OALD:

> He arrived breathless at the top of the stairs.
>   [image]

Why don’t they use **breathlessly**? I’ve learnt that there are some verbs such as linking verbs that can be followed by adjectives, but **arrive** isn’t a linking verb. Why is it followed by **breathless** instead of **breathlessly** in that sentence?

Comment: It's not being used as an adverb. As the dictionary entry says, it's being used as an adjective. It's the same as saying *He arrived (in a) breathless (state) at the top of the stairs*. It's just that some of the words that would make it obvious have been omitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The adverb 'breathlessly' would modify the action of the verb 'arrived' and bring to the idea of 'arrival in a breathless manner' instead of the desired sense: he arrived there *being* breathless (he was breathless by the moment of arrival).